# How to prevent cells from breaking across pages in Pages on Mac?

Tags: mac, pages

This is what I have now:

[image]

I would like to avoid breaking orange cell across pages. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you just use numbers?

Comment: No, I need text editor... It must be pages.

Comment: you can add text boxes to numbers.

Comment: @IronCraftMan unfortunately same problem exists also in Numbers while printing document.